# Multiple mediatypes at html img tag/base64

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to display multiple types at my img tag. The pictures are base64 encoded.

It works while displaying one type
`<img data-ng-src="data:image/svg+xml; base64,{{img}}">`

How can I add another type like png?

Comment: [MIME Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) :)

Comment: I can't find the answer I'm looking for. How to add multiple types.

Comment: What excatly do you mean with "multiple types"? If you try to mix png with xml, then it won't work.

Comment: I'm converting two kind of types to base64 - png and svg. I just want to be able to display both.

Comment: <img data-ng-src="data:image/svg+xml; {{img}}">
<img data-ng-src="data:image/png; {{img}}">

are your mime types then :)

Comment: I really do need to make two different <img> tags? :/

Comment: Yes. [Similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/979135/is-there-a-generic-mime-type-for-all-image-files)

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help. =)